# How can we limit the number of suggestions displayed by auto-complete in Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular material auto-complete to display suggestion based on user typing. As user types I make API calls and bring the data to be displayed. Now in some cases the results are huge in number say 500-1000 and hence the DOM stops responding.

I am looking for a way where I can limit these suggestion to some specific values and then increase them (on say scroll).

I checked if I could use `limitTo` with it like we use with `ng-repeat`, but it didn't work.
Replacing `md-items` by `ng-repeat` didn't work either.

I google around and found this https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1917, though this does not seem useful.

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this.

My HTML:

```
<md-autocomplete class="flex corridor_popup_autocomplete" md-no-cache="true" md-selected-item="corridor.delivery" md-item-text="item.name" md-search-text="deliverySearchText" md-items="item in querySearch(deliverySearchText)" md-floating-label="Delivery location search">
    <md-item-template>
        <span><span class="search-result-type">{{item.type}}</span><span md-highlight-text="deliverySearchText">{{item.name}}{{item.code?' ('+ item.code +')':''}}</span></span>
    </md-item-template> <md-not-found>No matches found. </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Can you post the html? there are numer of angular function just for this.

Comment: @Itsik posted my HTML, assuming md-autocomplete is familiar

Answer (score 12):

I spent a lot of time on finding a solution for an autocomplete list which shows too many results. It appears there is no solution for this.

However, I solved this issue by using Angular's SlicePipe (https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe). This limits the number of suggestions displayed. This was enough for my purposes.

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async | slice : 0 : 10"
[value]="option.name" (click)="displayImage($event, option)">
<small>{{ option.name }}</small>
</mat-option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice(0,20)` on your array result:

```
function querySearch(){
    var results = query ? $scope.enqueteurs.filter(createFilterFor(query, 'enqueteurs')) : $scope.enqueteurs, deferred;
    results = results.slice(0, 2);

    deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(results);

    return deferred.promise;
}
```